# HTML elements not properly stacking in Twitter's 'Bootstrap' framework

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm curious why the following won't display properly:

```
<div class="topbar">...</div>
<div class="container">...</div>
```

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) for the layout and the contents within `topbar` are on top of the contents within `container`.  Why aren't these divs properly stacking on top of each other?

Comment: Can you show us the page you are having problems with?

Comment: a screen capture/jsfiddle/demo site (in order of preference) would be very helpful in answering this.

Comment: Can you provide the CSS?

Comment: thanks for the quick replies.  I must not have looked into the documentation that well.  I had to change the default CSS properties in order to align to the page properly.  I was under the impression it was all set "out-of-the-box".  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer below so we can take this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the documentation regarding the use of the `<topbar>` element, it reads:

**Note:** When using the `topbar` on any page, be sure to account for the overlap it causes by adding `padding-top: 40px`; to your `body`.

Comment: by the way...it's more like 60px, just sayin' :)